# Level curves in a multivariable context

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I have a math problem which is:

$f(x,y)$ = $x^2$ $+$ $xy$

And it asks to determine several level curves of the given function f.

So far I was solving it this way:

$x^2 + xy = c$

$x^2$/c + $xy$/c = c/c

$x^2$/c + xy/c = 1

1/c = 1/$a^2$ => $a^2$ = c

x/c = 1/b^2 => $b^2(x)/x$ = c/x (cross multiply here) => $b^2$ = $c/x$

I wanted to know if this intercepts would be correct in order to sketch the graph?

Comment: Cross multiply?

Comment: However, I think everything you did after $x^2+xy=c$ is as good as useless, if not harmful. My advice is making the two cases (one $c=0$ and the other $c\ne 0$) and expliciting $y$ as a function of $x$ and $c$ when possible. The level curves will be $y_c(x)=y(c,x)$ for fixed $c$.

Comment: is it possible if you could show me how the cases would look like if c = 0 and when c does not = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(see image below)

The equation of level curves under the "implicit" form:

$$\tag{1}xy+x^2=c$$

(for any constant $c \neq 0$), can advantageously be written under a cartesian form

$$\tag{2}y=-x+\dfrac{c}{x}$$

which are curves with a vertical asymptote ($x=0$) and a slant asymptote ($y=-x$).

These curves are hyperbolas (with 2 branches).

If $c=0$, the level set (see form (1)) has equation $x(y+x)=0$ which is the equation of the union of these two straight lines ($x=0$ and $y=-x$).

On the figure, the different values of $c$ have been placed close to their associated curve, with 2 "connected components" (=branch) for each level curve.

**Remark :** can you "see" these level curves in 3D, i.e., as being traced on a surface with the shape of a mountain pass with 3D equation $z=x^2+xy$ ? Said otherwise, parameter $c$ can be considered as an altitude.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!